# unable to update single column in sqlite in android . Need to store the edit text values in db

Tags: android

I want to store the edit text value every time into my data base when giving a value into the edit text. I dnt know how to update my table. Every time edit text value changes here edit text indicates the quantity of the recipes I want to calculate amount based on the quantity so for that I want to store quantity value in db. please help me. how to store particular row value into db i can write update query but overall table updation happened there.
             Thanks in advance

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

        public class YourOrder extends HelperActivity {

            private ListView list;
            private DataBaseHandler db;
            ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            OrdersImageAdapter adapter;
            public static TextView toatalamount;
             EditText qtyView,quantityt;
             int total;
             double recipeamount=0;
            public static Button payment;
            public Integer id = null;
            public String name = null;
            public Integer price = null;
            public int quantiy;
            public String quan;
            double ordercount = 0;
             private Double orderTotal = 0.00;
             static String ordertotalval;
            public String setvaluefinal;
            int dbcount = 0;
             public double editcount=0;
            int count = NewBreakfastItems.getVariable();
            ImageHolder holder;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.yourorders);
                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                toatalamount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rupees);
                db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
                payment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buy);

                // Reading all contacts from database
                List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
                Log.d("", "------DATABASE CONTACTS-------" + db.getAllContacts());
                for (Contact cn : contacts) {
                    String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName()
                            + " ,Image: " + cn.getImage() + "Price :" + cn.getprice();

                    Log.d("Name: ", log);

                    Log.i("", "-----ID-------" + cn.getID());
                    Log.i("", "-----ID-------" + cn.getName());
                    Log.i("----recipe price---", "-----price----" + cn.getprice());

                    id = cn.getID();// Here i am getting the id no...
                    name = cn.getName();
                    price = cn.getprice();
                    ordercount = ordercount + price;

                    Log.e("---ordercount---", "----ordercount----" + ordercount);
                    toatalamount.setText(String.valueOf(ordercount));

                    /*
                     * count=count+price; Log.i("---count----", "-----count----"+count);
                     */
                    // Writing Contacts to log
                    Log.e("Result:========== ", "=====LOG=====" + log);

                    imageArry.add(cn);

                }

                Log.d("", "-----ID-------" + id);
                Log.d("", "-----ID-------" + name);

                adapter = new OrdersImageAdapter(this, R.layout.orderscart, imageArry);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                dbcount = db.getContactsCount();
                Log.e("----dbcount----", "-----dbcount---" + dbcount);
                payment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Payment.class);
                        //intent.putExtra("count", count);
                        intent.putExtra("ordertotalval", ordertotalval);
                        intent.putExtra("name", name);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
                footerBlock();

            }

            public class OrdersImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

                // Contact contact;
                Context context;
                public int dltcount;
                int layoutResourceId;
                int adaptercount = 0;
                public int extPrice;


                ArrayList<Contact> data = new ArrayList<Contact>();

                public OrdersImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                        ArrayList<Contact> data) {

                    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
                    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
                    this.context = context;
                    this.data = data;

                     this.data = new ArrayList<Contact>();
                       this.data.addAll(data);
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
                      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
                    Contact product = data.get(position);
                    View row = convertView;
                    holder = null;
                    Contact lContact = (Contact) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    db = new DataBaseHandler(getContext());
                    if (row == null) {
                        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                                .getLayoutInflater();
                        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
                        EditText quantity = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                        //attach the TextWatcher listener to the EditText
                        quantity.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(row));


                        holder = new ImageHolder();
                        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
                        holder.dlttxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dlt);
                        holder.quantity = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                        holder.recipeprice=(TextView) row. findViewById(R.id.recipeprice);
                        row.setTag(holder);

                    } else {
                        holder = (ImageHolder) row.getTag();
                    }
                       quantityt = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                       quantityt.setTag(product);
                       if(product.getQuantity() != 0){
                        quantityt.setText(String.valueOf(product.getQuantity()));
                       }
                       else {
                        quantityt.setText("");
                       }


                       TextView ext = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.setprice);
                       if(product.getQuantity() != 0){
                        ext.setText("$" + df.format(product.getExt()));
                       }
                       else {
                        ext.setText("");
                       }



                    holder.recipeprice.setText(String.valueOf(lContact.getprice()+"X"));
                    /* ====DELETING RECIPE ITEMS==== */
                    holder.dlttxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            Log.e("---pos---", "----position----" + position);

                            Contact lContact = (Contact) list
                                    .getItemAtPosition(position);
                            Log.e("---pos---", "----position----" + lContact);
                            Log.e("TAG", "" + lContact.getID());
                            db.deleteContact(lContact.getID());
                            // db.deleteContact(pos);
                            Log.e("", "======deleted=====" + lContact.getID());
                            Log.e("", "====NAME====" + lContact.getName());
                            quan = lContact.getName();
                            Log.e("---lcontact price---", "------lcntact price----"
                                    + lContact.getprice());
                            adaptercount = lContact.getprice();

                            Log.e("","quantity---"+quantityt.getText());
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getContext(), lContact.getName() + ":"
                                            + "Deleted Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();


                            //setvaluefinal=qtyView.getText().toString();
                            //ordercount=Integer.parseInt(setvaluefinal);
                            Log.e("", "-----order count----"+ordercount);
                            //editcount=adaptercount * ordercount;
                            Log.e("", "----edit count----"+editcount);
                            //Log.e("", "----order total value----"+orderTotal);

                            //recipeamount=orderTotal-editcount;
                            //Log.e("", "------recipe amount-------"+recipeamount);

                            imageArry.remove(lContact);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// updating adapter
                            count = db.getContactsCount();
                            Log.d("", "----updated count----" + db.getContactsCount());
                            HelperActivity.num.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                            //toatalamount.setText(String.valueOf(recipeamount));

                            // YourOrder.toatalamount.setText();

                        }

                    });

                    holder.quantity.setText("1");
                    Contact picture = data.get(position);
                    holder.txtTitle.setText(picture._name);
                    // convert byte to bitmap take from contact class
                    byte[] outImage = picture._image;
                    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                            outImage);
                    Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);
                    // db.deleteContact(null);
                    return row;
                }

                public class ImageHolder {
                    ImageView imgIcon;
                    TextView txtTitle;
                    TextView dlttxt;
                    EditText quantity;
                    TextView recipeprice;
                }
                 private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

                      private View view;
                      private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
                       this.view = view;
                      }

                      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                       //do nothing
                      }
                      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
                       //do nothing
                      }
                      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                       DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
                       String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
                       int quantity = qtyString.equals("") ? 0:Integer.valueOf(qtyString);

                      qtyView = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    // here i am getting the quantity value i want to store thid value into db
                      Contact contact = (Contact) qtyView.getTag();
                     // quantityt.setText(qtyView.getText());
                       if(contact.getQuantity() != quantity){

                        int currPrice = contact.getExt();
                        extPrice = quantity * contact.getprice();
                        Double priceDiff = Double.valueOf(df.format(extPrice - currPrice));

                       contact.setQuantity(quantity);
                       contact.setExt(extPrice);

                        TextView setprice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.setprice);
                        if(contact.getQuantity() != 0){
                        setprice.setText("$" + df.format(contact.getExt()));
                        }
                        else {
                         setprice.setText("");
                        }

                        if(contact.getQuantity() != 0){
                         qtyView.setText(String.valueOf(contact.getQuantity()));
                        }
                        else {
                         qtyView.setText("");
                        }

                        orderTotal += priceDiff;

                        toatalamount.setText(df.format(orderTotal));
                        ordertotalval=toatalamount.getText().toString();
                        Log.e("----total value----", "------total value-----"+ordertotalval);

                                   }
            }

        }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use primary key `id` compare to find the row,use update query(android SQL Query or raw SQL Query)to replace the value of the particular row.

Answer (score 0):

you can update using update method in sqlite,

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(update_column_name, value_of_update_column);

db.update(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, values, condition_field_name+" =?", new String[] {condition_value_});
```

Comment: Condition value means EditText value?

Comment: public void addqty(String qty) {
         // Get a writable database handle
         SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

         // Put the coun into a ContentValues object, with correct key
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();    
         values.put(KEY_QUANTITY, qty);

         // Inserting Row
         db.insert(TABLE_RECIPES, null, values);

         // Closing database connection
         db.close(); 
  }*/

 public Cursor rawQuery(String selectQuery, Object object) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }

 
}

Comment: i wrote singlecolumn updation like this

Comment: public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
  values.put(KEY_IMAGE, contact.getImage());
  values.put(KEY_QUANTITY, contact.getQuantity());

  return db.update(TABLE_RECIPES, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });

 }

Comment: I am updating like db.update(new Contact(qunatity)); where quantity id the edit text value but its not updating....

Comment: I think problem in where condition, Please check what is return method of updateContact, if this method return ZERO, mean no row should be updated. focus in your where condition.

Answer (score 0):

However to update row you are having `id` for it in your table. In `Where` condition use that id for updating particular row.

Try like this

```
 public SQLiteDatabase db;
 String UpdateVAlue = editText.getText().toString(); // Getting edittext value
 ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
 updateValues.put("ColomnFieldName", UpdateVAlue); // adding thevalues in Content view

 db.update("TABLE_NAME", updateValues, WHERE,new String[] { 
                   String.valueOf(ConditionValue) });
```